# When should I sent the invoice?

Tags: invoices

So I’m new at freelancing. I do it part time while also working full time.

I sent some final drafts over to the client over a month ago however whenever I check in with them via email they keep saying they are working on the content still. But I’ve provided the 90 second animation that was agreed so I don’t understand!

Should I raise this with them? What should I do next?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Did you perform some work for them? Did you deliver some kind of work? Do you have a contract? What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make a whole lot of sense...

> I’ve provided the 90 second animation that was agreed

and

> they keep saying they are working on the content still

What content if you've delivered the agreed upon work? At face value, based upon your post, this sort of sounds like a stalling tactic by the client.

Send an invoice now.

If you've done the agreed upon work, invoice. All they can do is question you about the timing of the invoice. In which case merely explain... you agreed to complete an animation. That animation is complete. Payment is due. If they need further work, you are happy to discuss that matter.

I will *often* send an invoice ***with*** a link to final deliverables.  That way clients get both at the same time and can not claim they missed an invoice if they want the final deliverable.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is structured in an unusual format so I'll provide brief advice based on the heading of the question:

- Provide an invoice to a customer at the beginning of the month following the work.  So if the work was performed in December of 2019 then send the invoice (dated on the last day of the month in which the work was performed, i.e. the 31st of December 2019) as early in January as possible.  Payment terms might differ by customer, but generally payment due by the 20th of the month following (e.g. 20th of January 2020) is fairly standard.
- I'd recommend getting into the habit of obtaining a Purchase Order from the customer to signify their commitment to the work packet.
- Lastly, when you invoice also needs to take into consideration whether the work is on a time and materials (T&M) or deliverables (goods received basis).  If the former, the the advice I provided in the first bulletpoint should apply.  If the latter, then ensure that you and the customer agree on the scope of deliverables (e.g. via a mutually signed statement of work aka SoW) before you begin performing any work.  Also an agreed approach/timeline within which your customer can accept the deliverable or raise any concerns to give you the opportunity to revise to their satisfaction).  Keep the timeframe as brief as possible because otherwise it will impact on your ability to invoice them which will hurt your cashflow.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your actual question, send it now, and then discuss future billing frequency.

Really you should have asked this of the client *before* you took on the work, usually when you negotiate the rate. I.e. I charge X per hour and usually I invoice on the 1st and 15th of the month for the prior period. I typically ask for a 7-day turnaround. Does that work for you?

Some people charge monthly, but I prefer to break it down into smaller chunks so that you aren't in too deep if they get difficult. To be totally honest, few clients actually make the 7-days but most make 14-days. However, If you bill monthly and then give them 31 days, you could be 30-60+ days out from the original work before there's even a sign that they lost the invoice. With a 7-day turnaround, you can check up on them 7 days after invoicing (14-21 days after the original work was performed).